# В чем/на чем/ как написать приложение

Tags: python, c#, windows

Нужно написать приложение(а может и не приложение)по типу hyperskript (грубо говоря это расширение для хрома где структура по типу: текст, который будет говорить менеджер и несколько кнопок, где ответы клиентов. Ну и в зависимости от ответа клиента кнопки и текст меняются на новые. Приложение максимально банальное, но не знаю как легче это сделать. Знаю про C# winform, но может я мало разбираюсь в этом, но скрывать кнопки и проявлять новые очень геморно и однобоко. Структура большая и в дальнейшем варианты ответом будут добавляться/убавляться ну и не очень удобно. По сути я уже сделал такое приложение на С#, но компания изменила структуру довольно сильно скрипта и в итоге легче просто сделать по новой ибо я запутался уже во всех кнопках. Вот я и спрашиваю, может я не знаю чего-то, что мне облегчит жизнь в этом вопросе?(может посоветуете статьи какие-нибудь как сделать какой-нибудь конструктор(думал даже о php devil Studio и Kivy) или еще какой-нибудь вариант)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Это предложение писать расширение? Честно говоря не вижу тогда отличий от Вин Форм. Долго и не гибко

Comment: Вы сами определитесь что вы хотите сначала. Кто говорил про расширение для хрома? Расширение пишется на Javascript

Comment: Лучший вариант - нанять программиста, для которого несколько кнопок не проблема.

Comment: Вариант: взять движок для создания игр наподобие визуальных новелл. Там как раз задаются варианты ответов на вопросы.

Comment: ну то есть у вас есть набор представлений (кнопок и текста) и переходов между ними. Если вы сможете описать это в какой нибудь xml/json файлик и после написать программу, которая рендерит и переходит согласно правилам из файлика, то вам больше не придется переделывать программу при изменении вопросов.

Comment: @tym32167 Да, эта мысль хороша, спасибо за комментарий